# Connect to SingleStore from SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, odbc, sql-server-2019, singlestore, ssrs-2019

Does anyone know if there is a possibility to connect data in SingleStore to SSRS?
I have googled this question but there are no(?) good articles about Microsoft SSRS and SingleStore.

Might there be a general SingleStore ODBC connection that we can use?

Comment: As I know Single Store is compatible to MySQL protocol. So search for MySQL ODBC connection.